# C#: Search for a line in txt file and the program gives back the value written there

Tags: c#, streamreader

The txt file has up to 300 lines, each line has only a number in them, the numbers are between 0 and 30.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. seems like a typical [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to me. can you please share what you've tried and researched so far? we'll gladly help if you're stuck somewhere, but you should first attempt to solve the task on your own - and be able to describe your efforts.
 i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It's not actually homework, just me trying to prepare myself for my advanced high school graduation exam. We didn't really had assignments like this in classes, since nobody takes this exam apart from me, so I'm not certain I have the knowledge to solve this task. The part I have a problem with is locating the corresponding line to the input number. I tried using a for loop wich ends with the input number's line, but I don't know how to make it write out only that line.

Comment: it is, however, _very very typical_ for homework. and the rest of my statements still apply. ***please*** actually do read the articles i've linked to ("preparing for exams" implies you _should_ be willing to _learn_ things), and ***please*** do show us what you have ***tried yourself*** so far (by **editing** your question) and be specific about what _problems_ you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this function in your program and call it:

```
find_string("text for search","list file path");
```

Return value is the line that contains it and if no match found a empty string return.

```
public static string find_string(string search,string path) 
// This method opens your list file and searches for the string 
// that you passed as arg1 then return first match.
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path)))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (line != null && line.Contains(search))
                    {
                        return line;
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }//close stream after reach to end of using block
        }
```